# Multiple Boost.Build projects

Tags: boost, boost-build, bjam

I have two projects using Boost.Build engine, with the following structure:

```
|_Project 1
| |_Source files
| |_Jamroot.jam
|
|_Project 2
| |_Source files
| |_Jamroot.jam
```

How can I trigger the build process of project 1 from project 2, and in addition link to the dynamic library that was generated in project 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember how to build the entire project 1, but for linking, you can refer to the target in the project1 as //library_project_from_1.

So if project1/Jamroot.jam looks like

```
lib first_library
    : # sources, etc...
    ;
```

Try referring to it from project2/Jamroot.jam as

```
exe second_program
    : # sources
    : ../project1//first_library
    ;
```